# Excel VBA - If Column A is blank combine Column C of same row with Column C of row above

Tags: excel, vba, merge, concatenation, offset

I have rows of data
Some rows are blank apart from Column C
If Column A is blank then I would like to concatenate Column C with column C from the row above - then delete the row. There could be situations where Column A has 2 or more blank rows, so that would require all those rows in Column C to be merged together

[image]

This is the code I used, but I keep getting a mismatch error - not sure where I am going wrong, but the error highlights the line with the offsets in

```html
Sub Merge()
Dim rng As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("test") 'Change your sheet name
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:M5600")
With ws
    For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
            .Cells(i, 3).Offset(-1) = .Cells(i, 3).Offset(-1) & .Cells(i, 3)
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try using `.Offset(...).Value` and `.Cells(...).Value`?

Comment: What line returns the error?  This can be done easily in Power Query.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the offset line returns the error - but i realised what the issue is - the data I am using has a - (minus/hyphen) at the start of some fields - meaning excel is taking this as a formula

Comment: Glad you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my comment is not very clear, this is what I mean:

```
If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
.Cells(i, 3).Offset(-1).Value = .Cells(i, 3).Offset(-1).Value & ", " & .Cells(i, 3).Value
```

(I also added ", " for readability purposes)

**Edit after comment**

```
.Cells(i, 3).Offset(-1).Value = CStr(.Cells(i, 3).Offset(-1).Value) & ", " & CStr(.Cells(i, 3).Value)
```

Is that better?

Comment: Thanks for your help - unfortunately I am still getting the Type Mismatch runtime error 13 pop-up - its so strange!

Comment: I think it could be my data

Comment: You might try to add `CStr()` around the values, in order to be sure the data are treated as strings, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this, I already created a find and replace VBA code to find all instances of "=-" and replace with "'-" which seems to work, just tested your one which worked without errors but those cells got renamed to "Error 1909" and didnt show the correct string, but thanks so much for this tip"